# Regex expression containing numbers and punctuation marks - Swift

Tags: swift, regex, uitextfield

I do not want numbers and punctuation marks to be entered in UITextField. I know how to do it but I need this;

What is regex expression that only blocks numbers and punctuation in Swift?

For example, the following only covers lowercase and uppercase letters as well as spaces.

```
let onlyCharacter = ". * [^ A-Za-z]. *"
```

Comment: Perhaps you can exclude matching any kind of number and punctuation character `^[^\p{P}\p{N}]+$`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Could this statement be erroneous? I also get an error in compile time.

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: "^[^\\p{P}\\p{N}]+$" It worked that way. I am using UITextFieldDelegate, the only problem right now is the delete key is not working. Do you have any suggestions for this?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no experience with swift, but perhaps you can create a new question with the specific problem about the delete key because that question is now kind of hidden in the comments.

Comment: Try `"^[^\\p{P}\\p{N}\b]+$"`

Comment: The text "" to be checked is displayed on the delete button. I solved this problem by checking the isEmpty. Thanks again for your help

Comment: @wiktorStribizew it didn't work. However, I was able to solve it by checking the isEmpty for the delete key. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
let unAccesibleCharacters = NSCharacterSet.punctuationCharacters.union(NSCharacterSet.decimalDigits)

let yourText = "Test case"
if yourText.rangeOfCharacter(from: unAccesibleCharacters) == nil {
  print("Your string contains only letters")
}
```

add " " to unAccesibleCharacters if spaces are not allowed too